# Swagger UI Authorization using IdentityServer4 returns Invalid redirect_uri

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, identityserver4, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle for Swagger authorization using IdentityServer. I followed these steps: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/ASPNET-Core-Swagger-UI-Authorization-using-IdentityServer4.

This is the log record from IdentityServer:

```
2019-01-17 19:17:41.031 +01:00 [ERR] Invalid redirect_uri: 
http://localhost:3200/oauth2-redirect.html
{
  "ClientId": "demo_api_swagger",
  "ClientName": "Swagger UI for API",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "http://localhost:5001/oauth2-redirect.html"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "anonymous",
  "RequestedScopes": "",
  "Raw": {
    "response_type": "token",
    "client_id": "demo_api_swagger",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:3200/oauth2-redirect.html",
    "scope": "api_data openid profile",
    "state": "VGh1IEph etc.."
  }
}
```

The log record says:

```
Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost:3200/oauth2-redirect.html
```

but I do not set this address anywhere and have no idea where it comes from. How can I set the correct address for redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect address with the port 3200 is hardcoded into the Swagger UI.

Fortunately, there is a simple workaround by adding the key `oauth2RedirectUrl` into Swagger initialization.

Swaggerinit.js (added into `wwwroot/assets` folder):

```
function createSwaggerUi() {
    var full = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '');

    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: full + "/swagger/v2/swagger.json",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
            SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout",

        oauth2RedirectUrl: full + "/oauth2-redirect.html"
    })

    window.ui = ui;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    createSwaggerUi();
});
```

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;

    ...

    options.InjectJavascript("../assets/swaggerinit.js");
});
```

This works with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI, Version=4.0.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the configuration for `Client` on the Identity Server 4 side. In the article example it's set to `http://localhost:5001/oauth2-redirect.html`, so change that to what's appropriate for you:

```
new Client {
    ClientId = "demo_api_swagger",
    ClientName = "Swagger UI for demo_api",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5001/oauth2-redirect.html"},
    AllowedScopes = {"demo_api"}
};
```

Comment: The thing is my configuration looks exactly like this code. There is probably some minor difference in the configuration that I need to find.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik Yeah, except you hosted yours on different port `http://localhost:3200/oauth2-redirect.html` from looking at your error so change to the right host port value. `5001!=3200`